# Lookup would require extrapolation into the past

Tags: ros, laser, scan, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon,

I have a problem when converting a laser scan into a point cloud map using ros indigo virtual machine. I get the following error :

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf2::ExtrapolationException'
what():  Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1467669390.062319560 but the earliest data is at time 1467669390.111446506, when looking up transform from frame [LIDAR] to frame [base_link]
Aborted (core dumped)

After running this code:

```
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>


class My_Filter {
     public:
        My_Filter();
        void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan);
     private:
        ros::NodeHandle node_;
        laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
        tf::TransformListener tfListener_;

        ros::Publisher point_cloud_publisher_;
        ros::Subscriber scan_sub_;
};

My_Filter::My_Filter(){
        scan_sub_ = node_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> ("/scan", 100, &My_Filter::scanCallback, this);
        point_cloud_publisher_ = node_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/cloud", 100, false);
        tfListener_.setExtrapolationLimit(ros::Duration(10.0));
}

void My_Filter::scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan){
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
    projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link", *scan, cloud, tfListener_);
    point_cloud_publisher_.publish(cloud);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_filter");

    My_Filter filter;

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239229/lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-past/) by [viki_rover](https://answers.ros.org/users/27454/viki_rover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2021-06-17**:
I ended up in this thread looking for a solution for this problem. But my issue was that I assigned a time to stamp `pc.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();` instead of separating accordingly in `sec` and `nsec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to transform the laser scan to base_link before you have the required tf information. You can solve this by either

- [Wait in the callback until the information is ready](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20(C%2B%2B))
- [check with canTransform whether the required transformation is available.](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Using%20Published%20Transforms#canTransform.28.29) If not ignore the data
- ignore the exception with a try-catch-block in the scanCallback. Then the first few messages will be dropped and tf will print a warning.
- [Use a tf message filter](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf::MessageFilter)

The message filter is the most idiomatic. Otherwise I'd recommend waitForTransform with a timeout.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viki_rover](https://answers.ros.org/users/27454/viki_rover/) on 2016-07-14**:
Thank you for your answer it worked !